# Swig given "unknown namespace" errors on namespace aliasing

Tags: c++, namespaces, swig

I have a header file like

```
#include <MyUtils.h> // defines namespace MyUtils, and MyUtils::Math

namespace mum=MyUtils::Math;

class LocalClass{

    public:
         void eat( const mum::array& arr);
};
```

I have the usual `%{  #include %}, %include` structure in my `.i` file.

When I run swig I get:

```
Error: Unknown namespace 'MyUtils::Math'
```

How/why doesn't SWIG know about namespace aliasing?
Is there a work around other than using `#ifndef SWIG` preprocessor macros? (c.f. [this discussion](http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/namespace-problem-td3808.html) (I need to keep my c++ code independent of swig)

SWIG Version 2.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose to have a header

```
// MyUtils.h
namespace MyUtils {
    namespace Math {
        typedef int SomeType;
        class array {
            //
        };
    }
}
```

And another header

```
// MyHeader.h
#include <MyUtils.h>
namespace mum=MyUtils::Math;

class LocalClass {

    public:
      void eat( const mum::array& arr);
};
```

If you SWIG file looks like

```
// MySwigInterfaceFile.i
%module MySwigModule
#include "MyHeader.h

%include "MyHeader.h"
```

You run into trouble, SWIG will generate code that cannot compile for a number of reason

1) You need to include all headers, SWIG cannot recurse header, i.e. you must include MyUtils.h in your MySwigInterfaceFile.i before MyHeader.h, the same applies for the inclusion using the %include directive

2) You must write using namespace MyUtils::Math; following the inclusions using #include

3) To make SWIG aware of any typedefs inside nested namespaces, you must write

```
namespace MyUtils {
    namespace Math {
        %typedef int SomeType;
    }
}
```

before the inclusions using %include

I recommend programmers to start out with many small projects to get hands-on experience with SWIG.

Comment: 1) do you mean #include or %include ?;  2) why using namespace MyUtils::Math? I've scoped everything in the header.

Comment: I mean exactly as I have written it. First you include using #include directives. For this part, you must include all files (SWIG cannot recurse headers). Next, you need to expose the parts that you want SWIG to expose, it is of course enough to include using directives for the symbols you need to expose. Further all protoypes must be complete, if a function take arguments, which are defined inside a namespace the namespace must be include, a function void fun(array* a); must be written void fun(MyUtils::Math::array* a);

Comment: I can send you a short example containing namespaces and templates (too long to put here though)

Answer (score 0):

SWIG does appear to support namespace aliasing. I think the problem is likely in MyUtils.h; maybe there are pre-processor defines that you have to set in order for it to use the namespaces. You can define those on the SWIG command line.

Comment: It is important that you include all headers in the .i file. SWIG does not recurse headers. After you include headers using the #include <someheader.h>, you should write using namespace SomeNameSpace; After you have included the headers using %include <someheader.h>, you may need to write namespace SomeNameSpace { %typedef int SomeIntegerType; } if you have used typedef's inside the namespace.

Comment: @JensMunk Thanks Jens I had a hunch that this was the case but couldn't investigate. This is certainly the issue, you should post an answer, I'll be happy to upvote it. If you don't have time let me know and I'll extend my answer.

Comment: I tried to put my comments into an answer. I hope this will help some SWIG'ers. There is not so many tutorials out there.